# [Ab]using Spark as a failover platform to run Java app instances

Tags: apache-spark

I need to run a Java failure-resilient application consisting of a certain number of instances, let us say 10 instances. Each instance is just one thread. When one of the instances fails or the node that runs an instance or several instances fails, then additional number of instances should be launched to replace the lost ones. Normally I'd use Kubernetes for this, however in the context of the project it is desirable to use Spark as the execution platform if possible, since the main part of the project uses Spark, so there is already Spark in the landscape.

Specific underlying cluster manager (Standalone cluster, YARN or Mesos) may vary, so it is preferable not to depend on it, but only on Spark interfaces.

Would it be possible to use something like this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;

public class RunParallel
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Run instances")
                                             .setMaster(...)
                                             .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        List<Integer> collection = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(collection, 10);

        System.out.println("Number of partitions : " + rdd.getNumPartitions());

        rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<Integer>()
        {
            public void call(Integer number)
            {
                System.out.println("Instance: " + number);
                try
                {
                    ... run instance code ...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ... log exception ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I would also like to understand is:

**What will happen if a node running one of the instances or several instances fails?**
Will Spark restart tasks just for those instances, passing each restarted instance again its number as the argument?

**What will happen if the instance fails programmatically, i.e. throws an exception out of call(...)?**
Will the exception be propagated out of rdd.foreach?
Will it kill other instances or leave them running?

**What will happen if the node running the driver fails?**
Will the driver (assuming it was submitted to Spark) be automatically restarted?
What will happen to left-over dangling tasks? Will they be auto-killed by Spark?
Will Spark wait for such kill to complete before trying to re-launch the driver?

Answer (score 1):

"Specific underlying cluster manager (Standalone cluster, YARN or Mesos) may vary, so it is preferable not to depend on it, but only on Spark interfaces."

IMO you should probably consider using the underlying cluster manager than to abuse spark to get this working BUT if you want todo this anyways your on the right track.  A couple thoughts, one you probably want to use a single cpu per executor so that crashes in one executor can't take out another application. Another is that the permissions available on the executor might be different than you expect.

```
spark.range(10).foreach(i => { ??? })
```